# need help building a stored procedure that takes rows from one table into another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

alright i built this stored procedure to take the columns from a stagging table and copy them into my other table, but if these four columns are duplicates it wont insert the rows, works fine.

however, what i want to do is if only the tour, taskname and deptdate are the same, then i will update the rest of the information. and if all four columns are  the same dont instert.

```
INSERT INTO dashboardtasks1
    SELECT [tour], [taskname], [deptdate], [tasktype], [desc], [duedate], [compdate], [comments], [agent], [compby], [graceperiod]
    FROM staggingtasks
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                     FROM dashboardtasks1 
                     WHERE (staggingtasks.tour=dashboardtasks1.tour and
                         staggingtasks.taskname=dashboardtasks1.taskname and 
    staggingtasks.deptdate=dashboardtasks1.deptdate and 
   staggingtasks.duedate=dashboardtasks1.duedate 
    )
                     )
```

i saw something like this

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;

UPDATE table SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1;
```

but how could i do it if my stated 3 columns are the samed then update?

or is there a way to do this with an if statement and use 2 different queries, but how would my if statement work would it check if the row exists in the table i am uploading to and then run the insert statement?

or what if i did something like

```
alter PROCEDURE test

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here


update dashboardtasks set
    duedate = s.duedate
from staggingtasks as s
    where s.tour=dashboardtasks.tour and
            s.taskname=dashboardtasks.taskname and 
        s.deptdate=dashboardtasks.deptdate


INSERT INTO dashboardtasks
SELECT [tour], [taskname], [deptdate], [tasktype], [desc], [duedate], [compdate], [comments], [agent], [compby], [graceperiod]
FROM staggingtasks
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM dashboardtasks 
                 WHERE (staggingtasks.tour=dashboardtasks.tour and
                       staggingtasks.taskname=dashboardtasks.taskname and 
staggingtasks.deptdate=dashboardtasks.deptdate and 
staggingtasks.duedate=dashboardtasks.duedate 
)
                 )




END
GO
```

staging

```
 62 3647    Request Space   3/30/2011   Land    NULL    1/6/2010    NULL    NULL    PEGGYH      NULL    NULL

    81  505 Rel. Space  02/22/2012  Land    NULL    12/24/2011  NULL    NULL    IMANA       NULL    NULL

    82  505 Ticket  02/22/2012  Air NULL    1/8/2012    NULL    NULL    SYLVIAT     NULL    NULL

    83  505 Names to Airlines   02/22/2012  Air NULL    1/8/2012    NULL    NULL    SYLVIAT     NULL    NULL

    90  505 Names to Airlines   02/22/2012  Air NULL    1/1/2012    NULL    NULL    SYLVIAT     NULL    NULL

   92   505 Names to Airlines   02/22/2012  Air NULL    1/1/2012    NULL    NULL    SYLVIAT     NULL    NULL
```

table

```
1   3647    Request Space   3/30/2011   Land    NULL    11/6/2010   NULL    NULL    PEGGYH      NULL    NULL

    2   505 Rel. Space  02/22/2012  Land    NULL    11/24/2011  NULL    NULL    IMANA       NULL    NULL

    3   505 Ticket  02/22/2012  Air NULL    11/8/2012   NULL    NULL    SYLVIAT     NULL    NULL

    4   505 Names to Airlines   02/22/2012  Air NULL    11/8/2012   NULL    NULL    SYLVIAT     NULL    NULL
```

results

```
  1 3647    Request Space   3/30/2011   Land    NULL    1/6/2010    NULL    NULL    PEGGYH      NULL    NULL

    2   505 Rel. Space  02/22/2012  Land    NULL    12/24/2011  NULL    NULL    IMANA       NULL    NULL

    3   505 Ticket  02/22/2012  Air NULL    1/8/2012    NULL    NULL    SYLVIAT     NULL    NULL

    4   505 Names to Airlines   02/22/2012  Air NULL    1/8/2012    NULL    NULL    SYLVIAT     NULL    NULL

   5    505 Names to Airlines   02/22/2012  Air NULL    1/1/2012    NULL    NULL    SYLVIAT     NULL    NULL

   6    505 Names to Airlines   02/22/2012  Air NULL    1/1/2012    NULL    NULL    SYLVIAT     NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you.

```
update dashboardtasks1 set
  tasktype = s.tasktype,
  [desc] = s.[desc],
  duedate = s.duedate,
  compdate = s.compdate,
  comments = s.comments,
  agent = s.agent,
  compby = s.compby,
  graceperiod    = s.graceperiod
from staggingtasks as s
where
  s.tour=dashboardtasks1.tour and
  s.taskname=dashboardtasks1.taskname and 
  s.deptdate=dashboardtasks1.deptdate and
  not exists (select *
              from dashboardtasks1 as d
              where s.tour=d.tour and
                    s.taskname=d.taskname and 
                    s.deptdate=d.deptdate and
                    s.duedate=d.duedate
             )        


insert into dashboardtasks1 (tour, taskname, deptdate, tasktype, [desc], duedate, compdate, comments, agent, compby, graceperiod)
select tour, taskname, deptdate, tasktype, [desc], duedate, compdate, comments, agent, compby, graceperiod
from staggingtasks as s
where not exists (select *
                  from dashboardtasks1 as d
                  where s.tour=d.tour and
                        s.taskname=d.taskname and 
                        s.deptdate=d.deptdate and
                        s.duedate=d.duedate
                 )
```

Comment: thank you, so much i will try it now, and this may be a dumb question but i am doing this in an if statement or all right after another

Comment: Did you run the insert statement? You have to run both the update and the insert. BTW the insert is the same as you have. I have not changed that.

Comment: Try using the second update statement in the answer. I believe that is the one you should use.

Comment: i tryed it, i posted what i used up top, but its weird because i added a row that is exactly the same and it didnt update either hmmm, i must be missing something

Comment: duedate is the only column being updated so its ok that thats the only one in my update?

Comment: You should fill in the rest of the fields where I wrote --etc

Comment: Same for the insert statement. You have to add the fields that are missing.

Comment: same but i just dont think it is running the insert statement after the update one

Comment: even if i just try the update query by itself in the stored procedure it doesn't update and the rows are exactly the same, besides the duedate

Comment: I updated the code using all fields. If your insert does not do anything it might be because the update changes dashboardtasks1 so the rows that should be inserted are already present. Can you post some sample data that I can test with?

Comment: its really weird because i copied rows exactly from stagging to the dashboard tasks and the only field that i changed was the duedate to see if it would update and it didn't, thank you for helping me ive been going at this for a couple days

Comment: the update doesnt work by itself i keep trying to change it around but its not working . i posted sample rows all the rows are similar to that

Comment: hmm could it be something to do with my primary keys, they are different in both tables?

Comment: Does it work for you now? If not please post data for staging table and target table. And what you would like the target table to look like after the merge.

Comment: Aha, I saw the new question. It would really be helpful if sample data could be added to that question.

Comment: it doesnt work but i marked yours as correct, because teh amount of help, ill post some more data

Comment: i added the data sorry its messy but if theres a better way let me know

Comment: This is great. I will look at this when I get the time.

Comment: this is great haha what this is horrible

Comment: Not at all :). I will use your data in my test tables and see what it does.

Comment: I posted a run through with the queries and your test data as an answer to the new question.

Comment: hmm i think it has to do with the way my tables are set up, if it has worked for you the question is what did we do differently

Answer (score 0):

A LEFT OUTER JOIN will do the trick

```
INSERT INTO dashboardtasks1 (tour, taskname, deptdate, tasktype, desc, duedate, compdate, comments, agent, compby, graceperiod)
SELECT s.tour, s.taskname, s.deptdate, s.tasktype, s.desc, s.duedate, s.compdate, s.comments, s.agent, s.compby, s.graceperiod
FROM staggingtasks s
LEFT OUTER JOIN  dashboardtasks1 d ON d.tour=s.tour and d.taskname=s.taskname and d.deptdate=s.deptdate
WHERE d.tour IS NULL
```

What you are doing here is joining the two tables on the values you want to match.

If there isn't a row in dashboardtasks1 where the values you've joined on exist (in this case tour,taskname and deptdate) it will insert a row. Otherwise it won't.

Comment: my query does make sure the row is not a duplicate, my problem is if the tour taskname and deptdate are the same, but the duedate is different i want to update that row and not insert another row with the same data but a different duedate. will an outer join do this?

Comment: It won't do the update no but the same process can be used. I was really trying to clean up the nested EXISTS statements (which will typically be handled as JOINS once the stored procedure gets compiled anyway) I've upvoted Mikael Eriksson's answer as he has stayed in your coding style much better and also explained when and how to do the update